# Generating Labels at runtime using kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Hello I currently have a window in kivy that I am trying to generate labels at runtime with, Needing to do this in python since the text that is contained within each label is generated at runtime and the amount of labels can vary. Currently I have this setup:

```py
class LabelInfo(Label):
    textOne = StringProperty()
    textTwo = StringProperty()
    textThree = StringProperty()
    textFour = StringProperty()


class SortieScreen(Screen):
    from sortieData import SortieInfo
    S = SortieInfo()

    def label(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.S.sortieType)):
            print("------------------")
            data = LabelInfo()
            data.textOne = self.S.sortieType[i]
            print(data.textOne)
            data.textTwo = self.S.sortieModifier[i]
            print(data.textTwo)
            data.textThree = self.S.modifierDesc[i]
            print(data.textThree)
            data.textFour = self.S.sortieNode[i]
            print(data.textFour)
            print("------------------")
            data.size = 200, 200
            data.pos = 100, (500 - (130 * i))

class WarframeInfo(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'Assets/icon.png'
        self.title = "Warframe Info"
        SortieScreen().label()
        return Builder.load_file('warframeinfo.kv')
```

While this does run with no errors, there are no labels generated on the screen even though size and position are set. Would anyone know what I am doing wrong? any help would be appreciated. Thankyou for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not a minimum running example.
I do not see where you add your label to the widget.
Label has only one text method.

In this first example i will try to fix your code.
You initiate your widget with 
`data = LableInfo()`
but until that method ends you do not add it to SortieSecreen()

```py
def label(self):
    for i in range(0, len(self.S.sortieType)):
        data = LabelInfo()
        data.textOne = self.S.sortieType[i]
        data.textTwo = self.S.sortieModifier[i]
        data.textThree = self.S.modifierDesc[i]
        data.textFour = self.S.sortieNode[i]
        data.size = 200, 200
        data.pos = 100, (500 - (130 * i))
        self.add_widget(data) # here you add it
```

Also i do not know if this is the best approach to add something at runtime. The problem is if you create many data widgets your app might freeze for some time needed to create and add the data widget.

Another approach is to have a KV rule defined. This will work if you add ~ 10-20 widgets. For more your app can be delayed.

in kv file:

```py
<MainView>:
    # main layout stuff

<MyBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical' #horizontal is default
    Label:
        text: root.label_0_text
    Label:
        text: root.label_1_text
    Label:
        text: root.label_2_text
    Label:
        text: root.label_3_text
```

and then in your py file:

```py
class MainView (BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(4):
            lbl = MyBoxLayout()
            lbl.label_0_text = str(i)  # Label.text only accepts strings
            lbl.label_1_text = str(i)
            lbl.label_2_text = str(i)
            lbl.label_3_text = str(i)
            self.add_widget(lbl)


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    label_0_text = StringProperty()
    label_1_text = StringProperty()
    label_2_text = StringProperty()
    label_3_text = StringProperty()
```

The best approach is [RecycledView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html?highlight=recycleview#module-kivy.uix.recycleview). You can refer to documentation example in the link.